# Are there US military bases where only singles can work?

Tags: united-states, military

As mentioned in [this article](http://www.news.com.au/world/asia/comment-conspiracies-more-mysterious-than-mh370/story-fnh81fz8-1226894919767),

> And surely you also know that all Thunder Cove military employees must
>   be single with no families?

Is there such a requirement in some US military bases?

Comment: While I can't find a simple source beyond my own military experience, no. There are locations where you can't *bring* your spouse/family, but there are no requirements that you *have* no family at any base, including those on Diego Garcia. I've known several people stationed there, some of which had families at the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can CIA or military be married?

["How to Become a CIA Agent"](http://money.howstuffworks.com/how-to-become-cia-agent.htm)

> If you're married, your spouse must also be a United States citizen.

Background checks and interviews may be performed on several family members and friends, no matter if the person if married or not. Most people have friends, even if not direct family. The CIA doesn't actually make The Boorne Identity as agents quite yet.

[Working at the CIA: Fact or Fiction](https://www.cia.gov/news-information/featured-story-archive/2010-featured-story-archive/working-at-the-cia-fact-or-fiction-part-2.html)

> In order to be successful in protecting the nation, much of the work of the CIA must remain secret. Some might guess that the life of an Agency employee would be one big secret as well. This could not be further from the truth. The Agency promotes a **family-friendly work environment** and always strives to find the right work/life balance.

**The CIA even has "Family Day.**"

However, as I said, while families are considered a great positive, some lying and omission occurs.

> This is partly true. There are many parts about my job I cannot share. But this relates to national security and protecting sources and methods and not because I am being “secretive” with them. I have told some family members where I work, especially my wife.

Perhaps this really the information being discussed:

> Normally family will not travel with you on a temporary assignment because it is short-term.  And, family can and often do accompany officers to long-term posts, unless there is a safety reason that they should not go.  Again, it all depends on what you are doing at the time.

**So, there are indeed bases without civilian family members allowed to be living there, but the soldiers and agents may or may not be married.**

The policy of the military is very similar with all of the above.

The CIA specifically encourages committed marital relationships not only to make employees more motivated. Those who have many relationships outside or inside marriage may be more easily blackmailed.

For example: CIA Director David Petreaus was forced to resign over an extra-marital affair. It was investigated by the FBI, too. http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2012/11/09/david-petraeus-cia-resign-nbc/1695271/